# External ejb-jar.xml

Tags: jakarta-ee, ejb-3.0, jboss5.x

I have to add custom functionality to a legacy EJB. I'm pretending to use Interceptors for such a task by means of ejb-jar.xml, since I cannot edit the source code to recompile it with the @Interceptors annotation.

Is it possible to define that ejb-jar.xml file outside the JAR that contains the EJB of interest? Currently, that jar contains its own ejb-jar.xml, so I need to override it or "extend" its definition.

Kind regards.

Comment: This question is pretty similar and graphically illustrated, to better comprehend my question; though, in my case, I cannot edit the preexisting JAR file: [Can I place all of my EJB deployment descriptors in the META-INF directory of an EAR file, rather than the EJB jar files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10552552/can-i-place-all-of-my-ejb-deployment-descriptors-in-the-meta-inf-directory-of-an)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible to define that ejb-jar.xml file outside the JAR that contains the EJB of interest?

No, if the ejb-jar.xml file is present, it must be stored in META-INF/ejb-jar.xml.

Take in mind that the deployment descriptor file is not consider strictly `source code`. You perfectly can extract the ejb.jar.xml, modify it (in your case configure Interceptor rules) and package all the pieces together again.

This practice is supported by JEE specification and it is completely legal. 
It is one of the advantage of deployment descriptors file over code annotations.

Comment: Thank you. Though I agree about decompressing JAR file to edit that xml, it's hard a customer to let a provider doing those kind of things, yet more, to receive an installation guide to do those things just to support our new component. I think Oracle and Spring teams are lost in patterns due to the use of annotations and file descriptors, **both** have to be externalized so other packages developed in a future may extend them without they themselves to be aware or decompressed, like when using META-INF/services feature. Thank you, kind regards.

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem with the component ejb library. If the library wasn't  designed to be reused in other modules/projects there is no reasonable way - only extract and modify the ejb-jar.xml.

If a ejb library should be reused in other projects is should not define a ejb-jar.xml. Than any project can include this library in its own ejb module using the META-INF/MANIFEST.MF Class-Path entry.

Another way is to create another ejb library only containing the interceptors and bundle both ejb libraries into a ear.